# Acceso denegado mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me aparece este error:
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Este es el codigo:

```
?php 

$server = "localhost";

$user = "root";

$pass = "";

$db = "ohvee";


$conect = mysqli_connect("$server","$user","pass","db")

    or die("ERROR");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

$insertar = "INSERT into wall values ('$name','$content')";

$resultado = mysql_query($conect , $insertar)
    or die("ERROR AL INSERTAR");

mysql_close($conect);

echo "Datos insertados correctamente";

?>
```

**QUE HICE MAL?**

Comment: El usuario root requiere contraseña y tu no le estas mandando la contraseña correcta.

Comment: Con proyectos de Github me va super bien, ademas, yo que me acuerde no le he puesto contraseña.

Comment: El problema lo tenés en la línea de conexión. Fijate que en el campo de contraseña pasás la cadena "pass" y no la variable $pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al margen de que te doy respuesta a tu pregunta original, te haré otras observaciones acerca de tu código, el primer error, es que no estás colocando la contraseña cuando claramente tu servidor te indica que la requiere

Por otro lado te segundo error es que primero estás trabajando con el driver de mysqli y luego mezclas con el driver mysql que ya esta en deshuso entonces mira los cambios que le he hecho a tu trabajo

```
?php 

$server = "localhost";

$user = "root";

$pass = "algunpass";

$db = "ohvee";


$conect = mysqli_connect("$server","$user","pass","db")

    or die("ERROR");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

$insertar = "INSERT into wall values ('$name','$content')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conect , $insertar)
    or die("ERROR AL INSERTAR");

mysqli_close($conect);

echo "Datos insertados correctamente";
```

Por otro lado te comento que tu siguiente falla es que así como esta tu código es sensible a SQL INJECTION, por lo tanto deberías hacer los siguientes cambios

```
<?php 

$server = "localhost";

$user = "root";

$pass = "";

$db = "ohvee";


$conect = mysqli_connect("$server","$user","pass","db")

    or die("ERROR");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

$insertar = $conect->prepare("INSERT into wall(name, content) values (?,?)");
$insertar->bind_param('s', $name);
$insertar->bind_param('s', $content);
$insertar->execute();


$resultado = mysql_query($conect , $insertar)
    or die("ERROR AL INSERTAR");

mysql_close($conect);

echo "Datos insertados correctamente";
```

1. Como notas arriba estoy con los signos de interogación usando marcadores de posición
2. hago uso del método prepare
3. hago uso de bind_param para setear que tipo de valor le voy a mandar: s es para strings, i es para integer, d es para double y b es para datos de tipo blob
4. Finalmente de eso modo al final acceso al método execute para que mi query se procese y se pueda llevar a cabo

Answer (score 0):

Hola tienes varios errores como por ejemplo no le pasas la contraseña a la conexion aunque no es necesaria porque estas haciendo el proyecto en localhost, ademas te recomiendo que uses Programacion Orientada a Objetos en php.

Aqui  tienes un ejemplo comentado:

```html
class Db {
    // The database connection
    protected static $connection;

    /**
     * Connect to the database
     * 
     * @return bool false on failure / mysqli MySQLi object instance on success
     */
    public function connect() {    
// Carga la configuración como una matriz. Utilice la ubicación real de su archivo de configuración
        if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
// Carga la configuración como una matriz. Utilice la ubicación real de su archivo de configuración
            $config = parse_ini_file('./config.ini'); 
            self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
        }

// Si la conexión no tuvo éxito, maneje el error            if(self::$connection === false) {
// Maneja el error: notifica al administrador, registra en un archivo, muestra una pantalla de error, etc.
            return false;
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }

    /**
* Consultar la base de datos
    *
          * @param $ query La cadena de consulta
          * @return mixed El resultado de la función mysqli :: query ()
          * /
    public function query($query) {
        // Conexion a la base de datos.
        $connection = $this -> connect();

// Consultar la base de datos
        $result = $connection -> query($query);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Obtener filas de la base de datos (consulta SELECT)
          *
          * @param $ query La cadena de consulta
          * @return bool Falso en falla / matriz Filas de base de datos en el éxito
          * /
    public function select($query) {
        $rows = array();
        $result = $this -> query($query);
        if($result === false) {
            return false;
        }
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

        /** Obtener el último error de la base de datos
          *
          * @return string Mensaje de error de la base de datos
          * /
    public function error() {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return $connection -> error;
    }

    /**
 Valor de referencia y escape para uso en una consulta de base de datos
          *
          * @param string $ value El valor a ser citado y escapado
          * @return string La cadena citada y escapada
          * /
    public function quote($value) {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return "'" . $connection -> real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
}
```

Comment: y que tiene que ver que sea en local o por que aseguras que ahí no requiere la contraseña?

Comment: I wanted help only

Answer (score 0):

Estoy haciendo mi proyecto en localhost tambien y usando un conexion.php

```html
?php
// datos para la conexion a mysql
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','ohvee');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME);
?>
```

Y luego en el php que vayas a usar usas:

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once "conexion.php";
```

Me ha funcionado perfectamente también sin contraseña.
Un saludo.